# Is there any "Review Alert" plug in for Android?

Tags: android, plugins, alert, review

i found a plug-in for iOs application. Is there any plugin like this for android aswell?

Plugin website:
http://goo.gl/yFTns

Sample screen:
http://goo.gl/GDtSL

Comment: Maybe this question on StackOverflow can help you [Android approach for “Rate my application”][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482783/android-approach-for-rate-my-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this android code snippet for rate your android application .

http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need a plug-in. You just count if the user is using the app (number of opens, time, something like that) and after a time you popup a AlertDialogue with an Intent ACTION_OPEN to your Google Play link.