# How to create Rate button?

Tags: android

I almost complete first game for Android (Hybrid app), I am considering create a Rate button for it. I try searching on internet but most comments talk about Java code while I don't know anything. Suppose that I created a button in HTML file ( Rate ). Everyone can give a solution so that it run as a regular Rate button?

Comment: the following link may help you[check this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514579/how-to-implement-rate-it-feature-in-android-app