# how to add rate my app popup message android?

Tags: java, android, xml, rate

i need to know how to add a message witch tell the user to rate the app 
for exemple i've been using an application and one time i get a message telling me : you look like you are enjoying our application could you take a few minute to rate us:
'//and i get those 3 button '
rate now 
remind me later
never ask me again
if the user press the never ask me again the message will never show
but if he press rate now it will send him directly to a google play page showing him 5 star to chose from 
thanks in advance

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14514701/1529129) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find many libraries on GitHub that make this implementation.

This is a good one: https://github.com/kobakei/Android-RateThisApp

Usually, you can simply copy the files in the com.name.package to your project. But you can follow the instructions provided by the developer to use it. It's simple and fast.

---

Another way would be to create a class like that or this one, saving the data on some sharedPreferences and control it yourself on every launch of the MainActivity.