# How to show Android-Rate dialog?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the "[Android-Rate](https://github.com/hotchemi/Android-Rate)" library in my application. I have a problem when I try to show the dialog.

When the dialog opens it has the sentence I put inside it, but I cannot see the button like in the image below:

[image]

As you can see, the text is showed but the buttons doesn't appear, is like the button are invisible but if you click on the white part of the dialog, it opens the App Store page.

Here is my code:

```
AppRate.with(this)
            .setInstallDays(0) 
            .setLaunchTimes(3) 
            .setRemindInterval(2) 
            .setOnClickButtonListener(new OnClickButtonListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClickButton(int which) {
                    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), Integer.toString(which));
                }
            })
            .monitor();
AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this);
```

I also put this code inside `Strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Example</string>

<string name="rate_dialog_title">Rate this app</string>
<string name="rate_dialog_message">If you enjoy playing this app, would you mind taking a moment to rate it? It won't take more than a minute. Thanks for your support!</string>
<string name="rate_dialog_ok">Rate It Now</string>
<string name="rate_dialog_cancel">Remind Me Later</string>
<string name="rate_dialog_no">No, Thanks</string>
```

Can you help me resolving this problem?

Comment: I can see an open issue with the said library https://github.com/hotchemi/Android-Rate/issues/123

Comment: Try changing your app theme, perhaps the default is white, which on a white background will be invisible

Comment: @SairajSawant Oh, I didn't noticed that, what would you raccomend me to use to do this thing?

Comment: @Jaime how do I change the app theme? Could you make an example?

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514701/6763544) or https://github.com/Vorlonsoft/AndroidRate

Comment: In your res/styles.xml change 'AppTheme' at the top to this     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFF00</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF00FF</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#00FFFF</item>
    </style>

Comment: Okay I changed the theme and it works thanks a lot man.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an aswer so I could check this question as answered?

Comment: use your own dialog rather than using any library

Comment: fallow this link & check its comments if you face an issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373688/9247273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your app theme, perhaps the default is white, which on a white background will be invisible

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"> 
  <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFF00</item> 
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF00FF</item> 
  <item name="colorAccent">#00FFFF</item> 
</style>
```