# Android in-app rating is easy; in-app purchase is very hard--any shortcuts?

Tags: android, google-play

At [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482783/android-approach-for-rate-my-application?lq=1) link, I found it remarkably easy to provide access to Google Play Store (GPS) for purposes of rating an app, although it does require that the user scroll down to the ratings stars. I also now use the method to provide an easier upgrade procedure by linking the free version to the pro version's location in GPS.

This was so easy that it's hard to believe that it's so hard to enable "in-app" purchases. I realize that, since money is involved in app execution, coding for upgrading has to be a bit more involved, but what I've found would take a month to get right.

Is there a shorter way of doing GPS in-app purchases other than modifying the ["trivial drive"](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3), makes life much easier.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer until (if) a better one comes along even though I'm not going to try just now to see if *I* can implement it via what is said at the link provided.